# Why DockableFrames does not work inside JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jide

I have a little problem with ([JIDE](https://www.jidesoft.com/))

I'm currently trying to put DockableFrames inside a JPanel but by doing that the Docking system doesn't work.

I tried various classes (DockableHolderPaner for example) as a holder for my DockableFrames but it doesn't work either.

My question may sound unclear but it's not clear in my head either.

If someone can give me a hint, it'll be well appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Found what I needed, I can put my DockableFrame in a DefaultInternalFrameDockableHolder in another DockableFrame in a DefaultDockableHolder :)